# Setting CSS inside setTimeout not updating

Tags: javascript, css

This is a silly question, however, I've been trying to find out the problem of this for a while and nothing is coming up. I've looked around and tested with logs, checked console.

I have a function that should edit the css of the element passed in the parameter.
The first sets work, however, inside the timeout function, it seems to be disregarded.

```js
function notif(elem) {
  elem.style.color = "rgb(200,100,100)";
  elem.style.borderBottom = "1px solid rgb(200,100,100)";
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.style.color = "rgb(200,200,200)";
    elem.style.borderBottom = "1px solid rgb(200,200,200)";
    console.log(elem.style.color, elem.style.borderBottom);
  }, 3 * 1000);
}
notif(document.getElementById('newTodo'));
```

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.input::placeholder {
  color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

.input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  caret-color: white;
}

#newTodo {
  left: 20;
  top: 10;
}
```

```html
<input class="input" id="newTodo" placeholder="Add new to-do task...">
```

The element being passed is valid and doesn't have any `!important` tags. 
I loaded this script after the css and html.
I've logged inside the timeout and I get it in the console. Even when logging `elem.style` it shows the targeted styles have changed but they do not show in my html tab.

If I've done something wrong or there is a solution to it, please let me know.
Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

The snippet produces the result I desire, however, in my webpage that result is not being produced. Is there any values which would prevent this that I may have?

---

**SOLVED**

Figured out that the reason why was because the element was later modified in another file I forgot about. I just moved the file to be loaded previous this function and it worked fine.

Thanks again

Comment: How are you verifying that it's _not_ working?

Comment: line 3 and 4 set the elements styles to red, which shows visibly when the html file is open and loaded, however, its expected that 3 seconds later, it should be set to grey, which doesn't happen visibly. Reason I say visibly is because logging the elements styles show that the value was changed to the grey rgb

Comment: If you right-click the element and choose _"Inspect"_, you can see what styles are applied and where they come from

Comment: Ive updated the question to exactly what I have but now I am starting to suspect that the error comes from my file and not the snippet of code exactly. Running the snippet does produce the result I want. However, that cant fix the problem. What could be stopping the editing of css in js?

Comment: @Sean add `!important` in your style

Comment: @Sean have you tried inspecting the element yet?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the script tag is at the bottom of the page.

https://faqs.skillcrush.com/article/176-where-should-js-script-tags-be-linked-in-html-documents

I would also use a variable in your javaScript

```
<script>
  const item = document.getElementById('newTodo')
  function notif(elem) {
    //...
  }
  notif(item);
</script>
```